# Get longitude and latitude from a shapefile with Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, centroid

I've been trying to map with `leaflet` to add `addCircles()` but my shapefile doesn't seem to have the latitude `lat` and longitude `lng` parameters so I got the centroids for each city as is the code below but it doesn't seem to show me the centroid points so I put in a df these values but I can't automate to get the points for n cities.

The data is [here](https://mega.nz/folder/Zg5RGYSB#zE68WEyAYFxnhDGpY4IfXw).

```
library(stringr)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
quito = st_read("C:/Users/crist/Downloads/Administraciones Zonales/Administración_Zonal.shp") %>% 
  st_simplify(dTolerance = 1000) %>% 
  sf::st_transform('+init=epsg:4326')

sectores = read.csv("C:/Users/crist/Downloads/sector.csv", header = T,sep = ";", dec = ",", row.names = 1)
sectores

full_data = inner_join(quito, sectores, by = 'NOMBRE') %>%
  mutate(label_map = sprintf("<strong>%s </strong><br/>Valor: %g<br/>",NOMBRE, TARIFA_PROMEDIO_POR_HAB_DISPONIBLE_...) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML))

bins = c(0, 10, 50, 100, 150,250)
pal_quito <- colorBin("Oranges", domain = full_data$TARIFA_PROMEDIO_POR_HAB_OCUPADA_..., 
                      bins = bins)

#I tried to do this because my shp didn't have the longitude and latitude variables 

full_data$centroids <- st_transform(full_data, 29101) %>% 
  st_centroid() %>% 
  st_geometry()

lngt_q = c(-78.41782, -78.67333, -78.4823, -78.60407, -78.36822, -78.50851, -78.56278, -78.3023)
lat_q = c(-0.08668143, -0.2179538, -0.1585809, 0.09029626, -0.4124271, -0.2112893, -0.311081, -0.2025039)

full_data$lngt_q =lngt_q
full_data$lat_q =lat_q

leaflet(data = full_data) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons(data = full_data,
              color = "#444444", 
              weight = 1,
              smoothFactor = 0.5, 
              fillOpacity = 0.2,
              label = full_data$label_map, 
              fillColor = pal_quito(full_data$TARIFA_PROMEDIO_POR_HAB_OCUPADA_...),
              stroke = T,
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
                weight = 5,
                color = "#666666",
                fillOpacity = 0.7)) %>% 
  addCircles(full_data$centroids, lng = lngt_q, lat = lat_q, color = "#045a8d", weight = 1, radius =1500,
             fillOpacity = 0.2)
```

**[updated]**
There's a way to get the longitude and latitude of my shapefile automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by adding the centroid geometry to your polygon layer with `st_centroid`.

```
library(stringr)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)  # I believe this is needed to make code above function

quito = st_read("C:/Users/Brian/Downloads/Administraciones Zonales/Administración_Zonal.shp") %>% 
      st_simplify(dTolerance = 1000) %>%
      #logintud y latitud   # this produced an error, thin it is intended as comment
      sf::st_transform('+init=epsg:4326')

## Adding the centroid of each polygon as a separate geometry column. This will not be active but can be accessed as needed
quito$geom2 = st_centroid(quito)
```

You will get a warning indicating that the centroids won't be accurate, because you are in a geographic rather than projected coordinate system and st_centroid assumes projected geometry.   I would guess this isn't going to cause problems with reasonably small sized polygons at lower or middle latitudes, but you should be aware of the potential for distortion.  If you need more accuracy, you could calculate your centroids before you warp into EPSG:4326 (WGS84). If you are going this route, you probably want to create the centroids as separate points, warp them separately and either join or use the separate points as your dataset to add the circles to your map.

At this point you can continue along the script as written until the last line, when you need to specify the geom2 column we created earlier as the data source

```
      addCircles(data = full_data$geom2, fill = TRUE, stroke = TRUE, color = "#000", fillColor = "blue", radius = 800, weight = 1)   ## I increased the radius to get it to display
```

[image]

I don't know best practices to share the leaflet here, but static image shown

Comment: Wow this was great, I knew I could make that way easier. To share the map, you just expose it in the Viewer like a regular plot.

Comment: I have a question, why can't I use the `mutate(geom2 = st_centroid(quito))` function? I'm not an expert with the dplyr package.

Comment: @cdcarrion  I think this is because the mutate verb from the tidyverse/dplyr expects something that provides a single output for each line like a mean or a sum type function, while the st_centroid is operating row-wise to begin with and returns a data.frame, so dplyr doesn't know how to deal with incorporating the data.frame- look at the output of  `st_centroid(quito)` --it returns all of the attributes.  I suspect that dplyr doesn't know that it just needs the geometry column.  There's probably a way of making it work, but I don't know enough of the sf package to make it work.